# Remmina Icon Lost After Updating Packages

Tags: linux, virtual, fedora-27

I can't bring up the launcher for Remmina anymore. I have to launch manually from command line and when I do, I get this message:

```
[jlefler@host ~]$ remmina
StatusNotifier/Appindicator support: not supported by desktop. libappindicator will try to fallback to GtkStatusIcon/xembed
Running under Gnome Shell version 3.26.2

(remmina:3815): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkMenuItem
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

When the program is running, the icon will appear in the launcher menu as a running program, but I can't select the item.

When I try to search for "Remmina" I only get:

Remmina Search Provider - Gnome SHELL Extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove %u parameter from both Exec and TryExec lines from /usr/share/applications/org.remmina.Remmina.desktop and relog.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm!